# Construção de Classe e Consumo de JSON

Tags: c#, json

Estou tentando consumir um JSON, porém na estrutura que desenvolvi o código não me retorna dados. Por gentileza, poderiam me ajudar e explicar o conceito do consumo e como funciona a estrutura de JSON?

Código que desenvolvi, não retorna os dados de LomadeeLink.

```
 var json = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://bws.buscape.com.br/service/createLinks/lomadee/7569446956636c7142716f3d/BR/?sourceId=28777832&format=json&link1=http://www.walmart.com.br/produto/Telefonia/Smartphones/Motorola/471928-motorola-moto-g-2-geracao-dtv-colors-preto-tv-digital-dual-chip-quad-core-16gb-2-capas-colori&link2=http://www.walmart.com.br/produto/Telefonia/Smartphones/Motorola/471928-motorola-moto-g-2-geracao-dtv-colors-preto-tv-digital-dual-chip-quad-core-16gb-2-capas-colori");

 LomadeeLinks produtos = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LomadeeLinks>(json.ToString());
```

Criei as classes desta forma pois o JSON retorna dados irrelevantes, só selecionei os dados relevantes que são os que inclui na classe.

```
    public class LomadeeLinks {

        public List<LomadeeLink> lomadeelinks { get; set; }

    }

    public class LomadeeLink {

        public int id { get; set; }
        public int code { get; set; }
        public string originallink { get; set; }
        public string redirectlink { get; set; }

    }
```

JSON

```
{
  "totallooseoffers": 0,
  "details": {
    "date": {
      "valid": true,
      "eonandyear": {
        "lowestsetbit": 0
      },
      "hour": 10,
      "month": 8,
      "year": 2015,
      "timezone": -180,
      "millisecond": 360,
      "xmlschematype": {
        "prefix": "",
        "localpart": "dateTime",
        "namespaceuri": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      },
      "day": 25,
      "minute": 37,
      "second": 14
    },
    "code": 0,
    "elapsedtime": 1,
    "applicationid": "7569446956636c7142716f3d",
    "message": "success",
    "status": "success"
  },
  "lomadeelinks": [
    {
      "lomadeelink": {
        "originallink": "http://www.walmart.com.br/produto/Telefonia/Smartphones/Motorola/471928-motorola-moto-g-2-geracao-dtv-colors-preto-tv-digital-dual-chip-quad-core-16gb-2-capas-colori",
        "code": 0,
        "id": 1,
        "redirectlink": "http://links.lomadee.com/ls/OUlzRDtMeThBa2FJaTsyODc3NzgzMjswOzY1ODM7MDs1NTc2O0JSOzM7aHR0cCUzQSUyRiUyRnd3dy53YWxtYXJ0LmNvbS5iciUyRnByb2R1dG8lMkZUZWxlZm9uaWElMkZTbWFydHBob25lcyUyRk1vdG9yb2xhJTJGNDcxOTI4LW1vdG9yb2xhLW1vdG8tZy0yLWdlcmFjYW8tZHR2LWNvbG9ycy1wcmV0by10di1kaWdpdGFsLWR1YWwtY2hpcC1xdWFkLWNvcmUtMTZnYi0yLWNhcGFzLWNvbG9yaTswOzA-.html"
      }
    },
    {
      "lomadeelink": {
        "originallink": "http://www.walmart.com.br/produto/Telefonia/Smartphones/Motorola/471928-motorola-moto-g-2-geracao-dtv-colors-preto-tv-digital-dual-chip-quad-core-16gb-2-capas-colori",
        "code": 0,
        "id": 2,
        "redirectlink": "http://links.lomadee.com/ls/aH5haTtDU0VPc2U2ZTsyODc3NzgzMjswOzY1ODM7MDs1NTc2O0JSOzM7aHR0cCUzQSUyRiUyRnd3dy53YWxtYXJ0LmNvbS5iciUyRnByb2R1dG8lMkZUZWxlZm9uaWElMkZTbWFydHBob25lcyUyRk1vdG9yb2xhJTJGNDcxOTI4LW1vdG9yb2xhLW1vdG8tZy0yLWdlcmFjYW8tZHR2LWNvbG9ycy1wcmV0by10di1kaWdpdGFsLWR1YWwtY2hpcC1xdWFkLWNvcmUtMTZnYi0yLWNhcGFzLWNvbG9yaTswOzA-.html"
      }
    }
  ],
  "totalpages": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "totalresultsavailable": 2,
  "totalresultsreturned": 2
}
```

Comment: Você verificou se os dados estão vindo ok? Isole o problema. Como você está usando uma biblioteca fora do padrão, é mais difícil ajudar. Complica mais não sabermos o formato do retorno. Mas parece estar certo, o erro parece ser o retorno da API. A única coisa que pode estar errada no seu código é não ter estes campos no retorno ou ele não vir uma uma lista de dados. Acho estranho você usar um `ToString()` em algo que já é *string*. Mas isto não vai causar problema.

Comment: Os dados estão sendo recebidos. Acredito que o problema esteja na estrutura das minha classes. O retorno pode ser visualizado acessando o link da variável json. Sobre o ToString(), realmente, é desnecessário. Retirei!

Comment: Já deu para perceber que a class está errada mesmo. Você está querendo guardar em uma lista o que não é uma lista. Eu nem sei como esse decodificador lida com isto mas o retorno tem listas dentro dele, mas não é uma lista. Uma lista (um *array*) em JSON é representado por algo entre colchetes `[ ]`. O que é retornado é muito diferente do que tem na sua classe também. Está retornando várias "classes". Pelo que entendi você quer pegar só uma delas. Eu não sei se esta biblioteca tem algum facilitador mas é certo que terá que filtrar só o que quer, via classes ou direto no JSON.

Comment: @bigown Só um aparte: a biblioteca que ele está a usar (Newtonsoft.Json) já começa a ser mais padrao que o próprio `DataContractJsonSerializer` que vem com o .NET. Até o proprio ASP.NET já usa o Newtonsoft.Json por defeito.

Comment: @dcastro eu nunca tinha usado e não sabia que ela era tão usada. Mas não muda o resto.

Comment: @bigown Nao, o comentário acerca do erro estructural está correcto, por isso é que era só um comentário, um aparte ;)

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, consegui com a resposta do @TobyMosque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note que você tem um titulo para o seu objeto LomadeeLink.
como você não especificou nada no seu modelo, o Json.NET vai intepretar o mesmo como uma propriedade.

```
{
  "lomadeelinks": [
    {
      "lomadeelink": {
        "originallink": "http://www.walmart.com.br/produto/Telefonia/Smartphones/Motorola/471928-motorola-moto-g-2-geracao-dtv-colors-preto-tv-digital-dual-chip-quad-core-16gb-2-capas-colori",
        "code": 0,
        "id": 1,
        "redirectlink": "http://links.lomadee.com/ls/OUlzRDtMeThBa2FJaTsyODc3NzgzMjswOzY1ODM7MDs1NTc2O0JSOzM7aHR0cCUzQSUyRiUyRnd3dy53YWxtYXJ0LmNvbS5iciUyRnByb2R1dG8lMkZUZWxlZm9uaWElMkZTbWFydHBob25lcyUyRk1vdG9yb2xhJTJGNDcxOTI4LW1vdG9yb2xhLW1vdG8tZy0yLWdlcmFjYW8tZHR2LWNvbG9ycy1wcmV0by10di1kaWdpdGFsLWR1YWwtY2hpcC1xdWFkLWNvcmUtMTZnYi0yLWNhcGFzLWNvbG9yaTswOzA-.html"
      }
    },
    {
      "lomadeelink": {
        "originallink": "http://www.walmart.com.br/produto/Telefonia/Smartphones/Motorola/471928-motorola-moto-g-2-geracao-dtv-colors-preto-tv-digital-dual-chip-quad-core-16gb-2-capas-colori",
        "code": 0,
        "id": 2,
        "redirectlink": "http://links.lomadee.com/ls/aH5haTtDU0VPc2U2ZTsyODc3NzgzMjswOzY1ODM7MDs1NTc2O0JSOzM7aHR0cCUzQSUyRiUyRnd3dy53YWxtYXJ0LmNvbS5iciUyRnByb2R1dG8lMkZUZWxlZm9uaWElMkZTbWFydHBob25lcyUyRk1vdG9yb2xhJTJGNDcxOTI4LW1vdG9yb2xhLW1vdG8tZy0yLWdlcmFjYW8tZHR2LWNvbG9ycy1wcmV0by10di1kaWdpdGFsLWR1YWwtY2hpcC1xdWFkLWNvcmUtMTZnYi0yLWNhcGFzLWNvbG9yaTswOzA-.html"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

neste caso o melhor a fazer é adicionar um Formatter diferente, no caso o [RootFormatter.cs](https://gist.github.com/4554127) e adicione a seguinte linha na inicialização do seu programa ou aplicação.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new RootFormatter());
```

por fim marque a sua campo com o titulo apropriado:

```
[JsonObject(Title = "lomadeelink")]
public class LomadeeLink 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string originallink { get; set; }
    public string redirectlink { get; set; }

}
```

a sua segunda opção é copiar a estrutura do Json na sua totalidade:

```
public class LomadeeList
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lomadeelinks")]
    public List<LomadeeWrapper> ListOfLomadeeWrapper { get; set; }
}

public class LomadeeWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lomadee")]
    public Lomadee Lomadee { get; set; }
}

public class Lomadee
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "originallink")]
    public string OriginalLink { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "redirectlink")]
    public string RedirectLink { get; set; }
}
```

**Dica**: Você não precisa e nem deve abandonar as [Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx), então use o attributo `JsonProperty` para mapear a sua classe.

Comment: Concordo 100% com a dica no final. Acho que as convençoes de nomenclatura sao muitas vezes subvalorizadas.

Comment: Funcionou, porém tive que alterar a a Naming Guideline de  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lomadee")] para  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lomadeelink")]. Obrigado!